# What are the eigenvalues of this arrowhead matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, characteristic-polynomial

Suppose $p_0,\ p_1,\ \dots,\ p_q$ are positive such that $p_0+p_1+\dots+p_q=1$. I am wondering how to find the eigenvalues of the following [arrowhead](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrowhead_matrix) matrix
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & p_1 & \dots & p_q\\
p_1 & p_1 & & \\
\vdots & & \ddots & \\
p_q & & & p_q
\end{bmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^{(q+1)\times (q+1)}.$$
where the empty parts in $A$ are all zeros and $p_0$ does not show up in $A$. Since $p_0>0$, we have $0<p_1+\dots+p_q<1$ and $A$ is a positive definite matrix.

I used the method $|\lambda I - A|$ to find the eigenvalues:
$$\lambda I - A=\begin{bmatrix}
\lambda-1 & -p_1 & \dots & -p_q\\
-p_1 & \lambda-p_1 & & \\
\vdots & & \ddots & \\
-p_q & & & \lambda-p_q
\end{bmatrix}.$$
We can multiply the second column of $\lambda I - A$ by $p_1/(\lambda-p_1)$ which could be added to the first column. Then we can eliminate the second entry in the first column. However, this method moves $\lambda-p_1$ in the denominator. It is still hard to find those eigenvalues of $A$.

Comment: 1/ Are the rest of the entries (not on the first row/column/diagaonal) all 0? Also, to clarify, $p_0$ doesn't appear anywhere in the matrix? $\quad$ 2/ Did you try the $ q= 1$ case? What about the $q= 2$ case?

Comment: So $p_0$ has no part in the matrix?

Comment: When $q=1,$ $p_0=1-a,p_1=a,$ then $\begin{pmatrix}1&a\\a&a\end{pmatrix}$ has eigenvalues $$\frac{a+1\pm\sqrt{5a^2-2a+1}}2,$$ according to Wolfram Alpha.

Comment: $p_0>0$ and it does not appear in the matrix.

Comment: So the matrix is full rank and positive definite.

Comment: 1) Since $p_0$ doesn’t appear in the matrix, we may as well say $0<\sum_{k=1}^q p_k<1$. 2) The structure of the matrix isn’t entirely clear to me. For instance, is the second row given by $p_1,p_1,p_2,p_3,\ldots,p_q$?

Answer (score 2):

Let $p=(p_1,p_2,\ldots,p_q)^T$. Using [Schur complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement), we get
$$
\begin{align}
\det(\lambda I-A)
&=\det\pmatrix{\lambda-1&-p^T\\ -p&\lambda I-\operatorname{diag}(p)}\\
&=\det(\lambda I-\operatorname{diag}(P))\left[(1-\lambda)-p^T(\lambda I-\operatorname{diag})^{-1}p\right]\\
&=\prod_{i=1}^q(\lambda-p_i)\left[(\lambda-1)-\sum_{i=1}^q\frac{p_i^2}{\lambda-p_i}\right]\\
&=(\lambda-1)\prod_{i=1}^q(\lambda-p_i)-\sum_{i=1}^qp_i^2\prod_{\substack{1\le j\le q\\ j\ne i}}(\lambda-p_j)\tag{1}\\
\end{align}
$$
Therefore the eigenvalues of $A$ are the zeros of $(1)$. I am not sure if they can be expressed in closed forms.